# Three time firing of click event on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing very simple problem. I am trying to add click event on the dynamically generated elements like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul').on('click', 'li.clickable', function() {
        console.log( $(this).text() );
    });
});
```

```html
<ul id="codingView">
    <li id="" style="display:none;" class="clickable"><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Here I have created two `li` elements dynamically.

The problem is that console is writing 3 times on every click on `li`. Why? Any workaround.

Edit

```
 var $box=$('#codingView li:eq(0)');
$('#codingView').empty();
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    console.log(this.topic);
    $box.find("span").html(this.topic);
    $box.css("display","block");
    $box.clone().appendTo("#codingView");       
});
```

Comment: Can you build a working fiddle (if possible with li not hidden) ?

Comment: First guess is you have nested `ul` elements. We'd need to see your HTML to be sure though.

Comment: Is there any chance that every time you add an item you add the on click function?

Comment: Can you post a complete markup and/or the code that produces the 2 dynamically created <li>

Comment: @Anton is right. I think that when you are creating the li dynamically  you're attaching a listener to all `li` and you end up with more of the same listener attached to the same element

Comment: @anton no its not possible now...because while creating new element, i am cloning the existing li element

Comment: Anything else that you did not post ? Is it the complete code ? Because it works in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KL3zt/). I just copied and pasted your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be nesting the `<li>`s inside of each other. I'd make sure the produced HTML is what you think it is.

Comment: i have checked its not bubbling effect.

Comment: You need to show your code then. What you have should work just fine.

Comment: yes its working fine...i dnt understand why its not working in my code...:(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working, however this seems to work fine [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKxag/)

```
<ul id="codingView"></ul>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    var cv = $('#codingView');
    cv.on('click', 'li.clickable', function() {
        console.log($(this).text());   
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) cv.append($('<li/>', {'class' : 'clickable'}).html('<b>I AM #' + i + '</b>'));
});
```

//Edit :
Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKxag/2/) with your new code, altered it a little :

```
$(function() {
    var cv = $('#codingView');
    $('#codingView').empty();
    var data = [{topic: 1}, {topic: 2}, {topic: 3}];
    $.each(data,function(){
        console.log(this.topic);
        var li = $('<li/>', { 'class': 'clickable'}).append($('<span/>').html(this.topic));
        li.appendTo(cv);
    });

    cv.on('click', 'li.clickable', function() {
        console.log($(this).text());   
    });
});
```